# Wiki recebe pontos na pergunta?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, wiki-comunitário

Wiki recebe pontos na pergunta? Porque achei que não recebia nada, mas tô recebendo alguns pontos, acho que pelos votos na pergunta... É isso mesmo, ou fiz algo errado ao criar, e não está como wiki?

Link: 
[Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/como-funciona-o-licenciamento-de-software-no-brasil)

Comment: [Como funciona a marcação de “Wiki da Comunidade”](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/762/91)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se sua pergunta for do tipo Wiki você não recebe pontos por votos nela, entretanto não é possível criar uma pergunta do tipo Wiki por métodos tradicionais, a única forma é sinalizando para um moderador e solicitando para que ele a torne no formato Wiki.

Isso acontece pois raramente uma pergunta é do tipo Wiki. Publicações do tipo Wiki são aquelas que são o resultado do trabalho colaborativo de vários membros da comunidade, mas isso faz mais sentido em respostas do que em perguntas.

Portanto, no caso, você está recebendo pontos pelos votos na sua pergunta e não na resposta que está no formato Wiki. E não.. você não fez nada de errado :)

Comment: Ah, ok, então acho que vou deixar assim mesmo. :-)

Comment: @gustavox sem problemas, pode deixar mesmo